# Android app crashes on tapping specific comment

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

Whenever I tap the first comment on [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222210/153011) (by user221081) in an attempt to upvote it, the Android app crashes. I can reproduce this consistently; I've also sent a report.

Nexus 5, Android 5.0.1 (Lollipop), Stack Exchange app 1.0.51.

Comment: @RobertLongson why would you want to close the question that is from 2014 and has a [tag:status-completed]?

Comment: @RobertLongson That statement implies that any post about bug that has a [tag:status-complete] is a candidate to be closed. I don't believe this is a common practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On today's edition of "Kasra hates the convoluted `if` statements he wrote": Did you think an `Integer` type can be null?!?

We were using that for maintaining user ids, and since user221081 doesn't have a real user id since it's a comment not belonging to a real user on this site... you can guess the rest.

Thanks for catching this! It's fixed as of the next update (1.0.53+)

Comment: That was the fastest acceptance of all time.

Comment: You don't know me ;) My accepts are much faster :) This one took the whole minute.

Comment: @nicael maybe I'll try fixing one of your bug reports then ;)

Comment: Well, rabbits are fast.